# How to display customized navigation on website?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, navigation, publishing-site, css

I have a publishing site with two languages:

English
Arabic

These sites have the following pages:

English
- Home
- About Us

Arabic
- منزل
- حول بنا

I want to display navigation on top depending on site opened. So if user is viewing English site then it should display Home and About Us links and if user is viewing Arabic site then it should display its respective links.

I have been thinking about it as to how to do it. I thought of using

> SharePoint:AspMenu

which has one property CssClass where I can define my custom CSS class name but it won't work because I have more than one CSS class in my navigation and I don't think this AspMenu can be customized heavily.

Then I thought of using CQWP to display respective page list on website but again same problem i.e. it won't allow me to use full customization and CSS!?

So I need to know how do I display List in customized way on website and that too in Master Page? If it is not possible in Master Page then please let me know if this is something I need to do in Page Layout?

Comment: Just turn on publishing feature and in Site Settings -> Navigation... First in English write "Home" and save it... after that change the language to Arabic, and in Site Settings -> Navigation... Change it to  منزل ... It doesn't require any customization!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, it's not necessary to customize things. I would  probably use 'variations' in this case to support your language setup (depends on license) . Each language represents a subsite, which has his own subsites and pages (childs). Concerning your navigation on top, it can be accomplished with the OOTB top navigation bar.

Comment: I am already using variations. But problem is it is displaying page links in navigation for both sites English and Arabic. For e.g. if I open English site then it is also displaying Arabic page links. Similarly if I open Arabic site, it is also showing English page links.
I only want English site to show English links and same with Arabic site.

Comment: You can manipulate this behavior with the navigation settings. Take a look at Arsalen's comment above.